# I couldnt change the image cropping code to be a defined image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

( im gonna try to explain my problem onemore time )

I found a script on the internet and you can see in this link :

[Link](https://www.webslesson.info/2020/08/php-crop-image-while-uploading-with-cropper-js.html)

But i couldnt change to code what i want.

Script start to work image upload but im gonna use defined image. Code must start with defined image.

for example : abc.jpg

If i enter to page or if i click a link, model will be open. And abc.jpg going to be ready cropping. I don't have enough jquery and jscript information.

I think i have to change this code which it is on below, but i couldn't change.

If you help me, I would be grateful

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    var $modal = $('#modal');

    var image = document.getElementById('sample_image');

    var cropper;

    $('#upload_image').change(function(event){
        var files = event.target.files;

        var done = function(url){
            image.src = url;
            $modal.modal('show');
        };

        if(files && files.length > 0)
        {
            reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(event)
            {
                done(reader.result);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
        }
    });

    $modal.on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        cropper = new Cropper(image, {
            aspectRatio: 1,
            viewMode: 3,
            preview:'.preview'
        });
    }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
        cropper.destroy();
        cropper = null;
    });

    $('#crop').click(function(){
        canvas = cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
            width:400,
            height:400
        });

        canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
            url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
            reader.onloadend = function(){
                var base64data = reader.result;
                $.ajax({
                    url:'upload.php',
                    method:'POST',
                    data:{image:base64data},
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        $modal.modal('hide');
                        $('#uploaded_image').attr('src', data);
                    }
                });
            };
        });
    });
    
});
</script>
```

i tryed so many time :

```
$('#upload_image').change(function(event){
```

instead

```
$("#abc").click(function(){
```

But it didnt work

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the issue including the related HTML that this code is interacting with.  This has nothing to do with PHP btw, I removed the tag. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: Also bear in mind that `didnt work` tells us precisely nothing about your problem. It also suggests you didn't do much in the way of trying to debug it yourself. Always try to describe the issue with meaningful details, then it's easier for people to help you.

Comment: Anyway my guess is that you can get rid of the whole of the `$('#upload_image').change ...` bit entirely, because that's related to the user selecting an image from their filesystem. Instead, just make `var image = document.getElementById('sample_image');` point to the `<img` tag where you want to get the image from.

Comment: And then somewhere you need to have a button or whatever which loads the modal when the user clicks it, so `$("#abc").click(function(){ $modal.modal('show'); })` or whatever (I don't know what `#abc` refers to because - as I said - you didn't show us the HTML).

Comment: Firstly Thanks for answer. You told me its not about php.. Yes i know but system wants 5 keywords and i cannot choice diffiret things. it doesnt allow that. Yes i said "didnt work"  and it didnt. i dont have a code because im using that script.. if it work like i want: im gonna change that code and im gonna include the php.

Comment: `system wants 5 keywords`...no, it wants _up to_ 5 keywords. Notice that right now you only have 4. Some questions only have 1

Comment: Anyway it sounds like you resolved it - the answer below is similar to what I suggested as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first;

You have a file upload section i guess.

In the js codes you gave;

```
var image = document.getElementById('sample_image');
```

This gets the element of id `sample_image`

And there is;

```
$('#upload_image').change(function(event){
        var files = event.target.files;

        var done = function(url){
            image.src = url;
            $modal.modal('show');
        };

        if(files && files.length > 0)
        {
            reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(event)
            {
                done(reader.result);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
        }
    });
```

And i think this one is file input to upload images to crop. So when anything changes on file input like select a file, it will run these codes.

```
var done = function(url){
            image.src = url; // <-- change src attr of image.
            $modal.modal('show');
        };
```

You can remove upload sections and give the `img` `src` attribute manually.

Comment: Im happy to hear you fixed it. No problem, Any time :)